# 3 notifications instead of one

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, key-value-observing

I'm developing simple MVC app in Cocoa/Objective-C. I have a strange issue (or misunderstanding) with notifications and KVO.

I have AppController object in MainMenu.xib, hence I implement `awakeFromNib` method where I register for `NSImageView` changing its `image` property. I add `self` as an observer in the following way:

```
// options:3 equals to new/old passed values in changeDictionary
[backgroundImageView addObserver:self 
                      forKeyPath:@"image" 
                         options:3
                         context:NULL];
```

The `backgroundImageView` is an `IBOutlet` in `AppController` connected to `NSImageView`.

In standard `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context` method I just log the received notification.

Problem is - when i change the `image` value of `NSImageView` I get 3 notifications instead of one. Can you help me with this? Maybe I'm overlooking something in options or in generally registering observer?

**UPDATE**: `backgroundImageView` is the instance of `BackgroundImageView` class which is sublcass of `NSImageView`. I subclassed the latter one for handling drag and drop operations as drag destination. When `performDragOperation:` is called (the last 'state' of the dragging) it changes the value for `image` property with `setImage` between `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`.

Comment: You should always use symbolic constants instead of numeric literals. If you want both the new and old values, specify the bitwise OR of those flags: `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld`

Comment: What output do you get if you log the change dictionary? (Please edit your question to include the output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … it changes the value for `image` property with `setImage` between `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`.

When you send an accessor message, you get KVO notifications for free with it. You should remove the `{will,did}ChangeValueForKey:` messages, because they're the cause of at least one of the extraneous change notifications.

Comment: I'm not sure why would any of `{will,did}ChangeValueForKey:` cause KVO notification, I assume those methods alone don't modify `image` property of the view, they only provide ways for extended class to disable change or do some extra work when value changed, do you have any specific reason or example?

Comment: Posting KVO notifications (without an accessor) is the very purpose of `{will,did}ChangeValueForKey`. When you do have an accessor, and you use it, KVO sends those messages for you.

Comment: See the relevant section of the KVO Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/AutoVsManual.html

Answer (score 1):

Is your AppController the File's Owner of two other nibs? If so, it'll receive an `awakeFromNib` message for each of those, too. MainMenu plus two makes three `awakeFromNib` messages, which means you'll add yourself as an observer three times.

Comment: AppController is an object in MainMenu.xib. It's not a file owner.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any obvious problem with setting of the observer.

Have a look at how you update the image that you observe, maybe it's being modified 3 times?

Comment: Eimantas: Are you sure you saved your changes? It's not showing me an edit.